# Vue-router loads a component of another route when using Memory mode

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering

Created a vite + vue3 + vuetify3 + nodejs assembly to implement SSR. When setting up vue-router, I use Memory mode and face the problem that if I switch to any route other than the root one, the necessary component starts loading in the browser first, but then the root route component loads immediately. This does not happen if the redirect is made through the methods of vue-router (router.push('/entrance')), in this case everything works out correctly.
Is this correct behavior or not? Is there any way around this?

On my nodejs side, a middleware has been added to the express router settings, which should catch all requests coming to the server and client parts, check whether the user is authorized and, if not, redirect to the authorization/registration page. Is it possible to implement this somehow, or is it worth considering another version of the project architecture?

vue-router:

```
import {
    createMemoryHistory,
    createRouter as _createRouter,
    createWebHistory,
} from "vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/'
    },
    {
        path: '/playground',
        component: () => import('../views/PlaygroundView.vue'),
        meta: {
            layout: 'MainLayout'
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/entrance',
        component: () => import('../views/EntranceView.vue'),
        meta: {
            layout: 'EntranceLayout'
        }
    }
];

export const createRouter = () =>
    _createRouter({
        history: import.meta.env.VITE_SSR
            ? createMemoryHistory('/')
            : createWebHistory('/'),
        routes,
    });
```

server.js:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('(?!(/api/login|/api/signup|/api/log/add|/entrance|/socket.io))', authCheckMiddleware)

createApiRoutes(app, passport)

app.use('(?!(^\/api\b/))', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = req.originalUrl;
        let template = await getIndexHTML();

        let render = null;
        if (isProd) {
            render = (await import('./dist/server/main-server.js')).render;
        } else {
            template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);
            render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule(resolve('./src/main-server.js'))).render;
        }

        const [appHtml, preloadLinks] = await render(url, manifest);

        const html = template
            .replace(`<!--preload-links-->`, preloadLinks)
            .replace('<!--app-html-->', appHtml)

        res.status(200).set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }).end(html)

    } catch (err) {
        if (vite) {
            vite.ssrFixStacktrace(err)
        }

        res.status(500).end(err.stack);
    }
})

return { server, vite }
```

middleware.js:

```
const authCheck = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.authenticated = true;
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('/entrance');
}

export { authCheck }
```

Please help me solve this problem. I tried different options, such as clearing the cache, but it didn't help, because the problem is in vue-router